# Windows 10 IIS MySQL reulting in a blank localhost

Tags: mysql, iis, phpmyadmin, localhost

I am a student. My intention is to develop a website.

Edition: Windows 10 Home installed

I ticked the Internet Information Services, which resulted in having aspnet_client in the wwwroot.

MySQL 5.7.10 and phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1 are installed.

When I type localhost in the browser the page is blank.

Thanks Michael

Comment: What are you expecting to see? If the only thing in wwwroot is the aspnet_client folder, you probably don't have any files and, depending how your error handling is set up, IIS might give a blank page instead of a 404.

Comment: Thank you Isaac. My wwwroot contains the following:

Comment: aspnet client, PhpMyAdmin, the prepared website and iisstart. What I shall arrange or add more?

Comment: Thank you for your help Michael

Comment: Then try loading `http://localhost/PhpMyAdmin/index.php`. You may also find some hints in the webserver error log.